# FragmentPagerAdapter.getItemId() seems to be missing

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

I'm trying to write a custom `FragmentPagerAdapter` class for use with a `ViewPager` and ActionBarSherlock.  I want to override the `getItemId()` method because I have different tabs that can come and go depending on the state of the app.  But the `getItemId()` method doesn't exist in the `FragmentPagerAdapter` implementation included in android-support-v4.jar (I'm using ActionBarSherlock 4.1.0).  I downloaded 4.2.0, but it seems to have an identical android-support-v4.jar.

From what I an tell, getItemId() was added to the Android support library on May 10.

Is there a way to fix this?

-- Edit --

Maybe the Android docs are out of sync with the support library?

Here's the link to the doc that says the v4 support library has getItemId(): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html#getItemId(int)

But I just downloaded the latest android-support-v4.jar from the Android SDK Manager (Android Support Library Rev 11). The jar is different than ABS, but it still seems to not include the getItemId() method.

The change that added getItemId() seems to have gone into the v13 library instead? See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/1a1c2acbc15f8bc9dba05d09dcb18e340474e1c6%5E!/

Here's some code from my project:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;

public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
{
    ...
    // This fails to compile:
    // The method getItemId(int) of type TabsAdapter must override or implement a supertype method
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0; // TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see a code snippet of what you're doing? Specifically the class declaration and the `getItemId()` as you're trying to override it? I just looked in one of my `FragmentPagerAdapter`s using the latest v4 support library and I do see it.

Comment: Added a code snippet. Thanks for any help!

Comment: That looks like the same code that would work for me. What's the filesize of your v4 library?

Comment: The size of the android-support-v4.jar I just got from the Android SDK Manager is 385685.  I copied this into the ABS folder (overwrote the old lib) and cleaned/rebuilt both the ABS project and my project in Eclipse. No luck.

Comment: Whoops, I just realized I copied the new JAR into the wrong location. I copied into into the right location of the ABS library and now the project compiles.  I don't know yet if it will work, though (hope there are no incompatibilities).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to overwrite the android-support-v4.jar in the ActionBarSherlock library with the JAR I downloaded from the Android SDK Manager (Android Support Library Rev 11).  I guess the ABS library just isn't up-to-date with the very latest release.  Luckily there doesn't seem to be any compatibility problems.